# FilterRegistrationBean url pattern

Tags: spring

I created a filter class.
In a config class I have created this bean

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean tenantFilterRegistration() {
    FilterRegistrationBean result = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    result.setFilter(this.userFilter());

    //result.addUrlPatterns("/queries/123/adm");// filter class called
    result.addUrlPatterns("/queries/*/adm"); // filter class not called

    return result;
}
```

I need to manage all this url

```
put
/queries/{uid}
/queries/{id}/adm
/queries/{id}/person/{personId}

post
/queries/{id}/person

delete
/queries/{id}/person/{personId}
```

Comment: A URL pattern can have only one wildcard, and it must be first or last: `/some/path/*` or `*.ext`

Comment: ok will check that, that very very limited functionnality